# cURL returning NULL after sending a query to a URL

Tags: php, curl, ebay-api

I have a problem with my code. So I have already read many posts on Stackoverflow and the documentation of eBay APIs. But I still can't get it to work.

I have already tried to change the 'setopt' variables but it doesn't work.

Note: The Code is inside a constructor function.

```
    $headers = [
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($user_key . ":" . $user_secret),
    ];

    $body = http_build_query([
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $oauth,
        'redirect_uri' => $runame,
    ]);

    switch($action){
        case "import-products":
            $cmd = "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory";
            break;
        default:
            $cmd = "";
            break;
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    if(curl_errno($curl)){
        print curl_error($curl);
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    if($err){
        echo "cURL Error: ".$err;
    }else{
        echo "cURL Successful: ";
        var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
        echo "\n";
    }
```

The result is always 'cURL Successful: NULL' but I want to get my entire inventory in JSON Format instead of the NULL.

Comment: That proves that `$response` is not JSON. What is it then?

Comment: What proves that the `$response` is not JSON? I want to have a JSON

Comment: You say that curl returns `null` because `json_decode($response, true)` is `null` but that doesn't mean that curl returns `null`, it only means that it doesn't return JSON. It could be returning anything else, for instance, an error message.

Comment: Yeah, just fixed it and now it returns a `string(0)`... but thanks, I never thought this way.

Comment: What [`CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) do you get?